# Grouping time series data by combination of time and day of the week

Tags: r, plot, time-series, aggregate

I have data on the occupancy rate of a specific parking garage for a time period of multiple weeks with a 5 minute time interval.

My data looks as follows:

```
head(DataParking)
           DateTime OccupancyRate Weekday
2017-01-27 10:24:41     0.2570423  Friday
2017-01-27 10:29:41     0.2605634  Friday
2017-01-27 10:34:41     0.2535211  Friday
2017-01-27 10:39:41     0.2535211  Friday
2017-01-27 10:44:41     0.2535211  Friday
2017-01-27 10:49:41     0.2535211  Friday
```

I would like to create a plot of average occupancy and lower and upper boundary values in order to show the overall weekly pattern. Therefore, my data needs to be grouped by a combination of time of the day and day of the week.

In the end, I would like my data to look like the following:

```
        Time   Weekday  AvgOccupancyRate  MinOccupancyRate    MaxOccupancyRate
    10:24:41    Friday         0.2570423         0.1770423           0.3670423
    10:29:41    Friday         0.2605634         0.1810423           0.3560423
    10:34:41    Friday         0.2535211         0.1870423           0.3570423
    10:39:41    Friday         0.2535211         0.1770423           0.3570423
    10:44:41    Friday         0.2535211         0.1770423           0.3570423
    10:49:41    Friday         0.2535211         0.1870423           0.3870423
```

How can I achieve this?

Another question: With this data I can plot the data of one specific day (e.g. Friday), which already gives some insights. However, if I would like to plot the weekly pattern from Monday 00:00 up to Sunday 23:59, I think I need to have a WeekdayTime combination variable, which can be plotted on the x-axis of a line chart. Do you have any idea if such a format exists and how I can plot a Weekday-Time combination on the x-axis with (for instance) ggplot?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: one quick way to extract the time is to use `format(as.POSIXct("2017-01-27 10:24:41"), "%H:%M:%S")`. This should sort logically as 0s are prepended to single digits (9:00:00 becomes 09:00:00). I think the `chron` package may have the facility to store time in a more intelligent manner.

Comment: Yes, I know how I can extract the time from the DateTime variable. But if I do it this way, my data can not be aggregated based on time, right? In case I use `as.POSIXct`, underneath the `%H:%M:%S` in the variable the corresponding date will always hinder the aggregation based on weekday, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a grouped `data.frame` to plot what you need you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(Time = format(DateTime, '%u %H:%M:%S')) %>% 
    group_by(Time, Weekday) %>% # Weekday is not really needed but can be clearer to read
    summarize(AvgOccRate = mean(OccupancyRate),
              MinOccRate = min(OccupancyRate),
              MaxOccRate = max(OccupancyRate)) -> res
```

The important bit here is `format(DateTime, '%u %H:%M:%S')` this create a new variable with `%u` as the weekday and `%H:%M:%S` as the time.

To then plot use something along the line of:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(res, aes(Time, group = 1)) +
    geom_line(aes(Time, AvgOccRate)) +
    geom_line(aes(Time, MinOccRate), alpha = .5) +
    geom_line(aes(Time, MaxOccRate), alpha = .5)
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to calculate the upper and lower boundaries of a 95% confidence interval instead of min or max values for a particular weekday/time combination?

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer your first question.

Using `dplyr` we can first create the time and weekday, and then do a simple `summarise`. This is untested since your data doesn't have different combinations.

```
library(dplyr)

DataParking %>%
  mutate(time = format(as.POSIXct(DateTime), "%H:%M:%S"),             # Thanks to @lmo
         weekday = lubridate::wday(DateTime, label = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(time, weekday) %>%
  summarise(AvgOccupancyRate = mean(OccupancyRate),
            MinOccupancyRate = min(OccupancyRate),
            MaxOccupancyRate = max(OccupancyRate)) %>%
  select(-DateTime)
```